# how create mvc 4 modular application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, modular

i want to create modular application in asp mvc 4 like joomla cms and i want to use area for modules
and create new solution for  Each modules where each modules is 3 layer (service layer- domain classes - Model) . 
I use Code first.

how to implement it?

Answer (score 4):

this article is best solution

http://geekswithblogs.net/cokobware/archive/2013/01/15/asp.net-mvc-4-pluggable-application-modules.aspx

Regards